# Set default global Print Preferences with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, c#-4.0

Objective: I am trying to create a simple console app whose functionality is to set default print preferences for my local machine. Any local application that accesses the printer will use this setting by default.

Below are the properties that am trying to set default values

1. Paper Type
2. Paper Orientation
3. Margin
4. Default Printer

I have implemented the below code with little use,

```
 using (ManagementObjectSearcher objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer"))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = objectSearcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in objectCollection)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(mo["Name"].ToString(), "OneNote", true) == 0)
                    {
                        mo.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null, null);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Even the default printer get updated, but every time when I do `ctrl+p` a different printer is selected 
[image: Even the default printer changes, every time I do <code>ctrl+p</code> a different printer is selected]

Secondly, I have implemented the below code to modify HKCU, but it is not providing intended results.

```
        string pageSetupKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\PageSetup";
        bool isWritable = true;

        RegistryKey rKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(pageSetupKey, isWritable);

        rKey.SetValue("margin_bottom",1000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        rKey.SetValue("margin_top", 1000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        rKey.SetValue("margin_left", 1000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        rKey.SetValue("margin_right", 1000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

kindly clarify that what I intend to do is achievable and the ways to achieve it.
I have also referred to other posts and questions which are not helpful.
Note: I want to make these changes, not on the process/program basis but for the current user.

Comment: [SetDefaultPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setdefaultprinter). [SetPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setprinter). The registry is not a programming interface.

Comment: @IInspectable At least is there a way to bypass Print Dialog?

Comment: Can this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc27aec1-803b-4c9e-82ee-aed31abaeda3/how-to-update-quotprinting-defaultsquot-from-printer-properties-quotadvancedquot-tab?forum=csharpgeneral) give you some help?

Comment: If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.